# Select only option - radio button- Dynamic form - Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using yii2 dynamic form to create questions with multiple,unique or sustain options. Within the dynamic form, I have a combo that allows you to select the type of question. at the you select the question type of the combo, it will call a JavaScript function to change the input `correct-option`to a type check-box or radio, or in any case eliminate and hide the inputs `option`and `correct option`. Currently have 2 problems, the first is when `correct-option`is radio I'can select more than 1 option and what I want is that it only allows me to select 1 option as correct, I do not know if it is feasible to use `radiolist` instead of radio. lo segundo es que el check-box  `justified`changes when you select the type of question.

This is my code.

_Form

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'dynamic-form',
    "enableAjaxValidation" => true,
]);
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->input('title', ['placeholder' => "Title Evaluation"]) ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_start')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'calendarWeeks' => true,
                        'daysOfWeekDisabled' => [0, 5],
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'todayBtn' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'date_end')->widget(DateTimePicker::className(), [
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Select Date --'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, "type_evaluation_id")->dropDownList(
                        ArrayHelper::map(EvalTipo::find()->all(), 'id', 'description'), [
                    'prompt' => '-- Select Type --'
                ]);
                ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?=
                $form->field($model, 'duration')->widget(TimePicker::className(), [
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showSeconds' => true,
                        'showMeridian' => false,
                        'minuteStep' => 1,
                        'secondStep' => 5,
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'qualification')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Qualification']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 9, 'placeholder' => 'Enter evaluation description']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="box box-success box-solid">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Questions Evaluation</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 30, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelQuestion[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'item',
                    'puntuacion',
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th style="width: 500px;">Options</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 90px;">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="container-items">
                    <?php foreach ($modelQuestion as $indexQuestion => $modelQuestions): ?>
                        <tr class="item">
                            <td class="vcenter">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <td class="vcenter">1.</td>
                                    <td class="vcenter">
                                        <?php
                                        // necessary for update action.
                                        if (!$modelQuestions->isNewRecord) {
                                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]id");
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        <?= $form->field ( $modelQuestion , "[{$indexQuestion}]question" )->dropDownList (
                                                ArrayHelper::map(QuestType::find()->all() , 'id' , 'description' ) , [
                                            'prompt' => '-- Select Question --'
                                        ] ); ?>
                                        <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]question")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title question']) ?>
                                       <?= $form->field($modelQuestions, "[{$indexQuestion}]score")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Score']) ?><?= $form->field($modelQuestions,"[{$indexQuestion}]justified ")->checkbox(array('label'=>'','labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),                    ))->label('You want a response justified ?');?>
                                    </td>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=
                                $this->render('_form-opc', [
                                    'form' => $form,
                                    'indexQuestion' => $indexQuestion,
                                    'modelsOpc'=>$modelsOpc[$indexQuestion],
                                ])
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px; verti">
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Crear' : '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span>  Modificar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

_form-opc

```
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_inner',
'widgetBody' => '.container-opciones',
'widgetItem' => '.opcion-item',
'limit' => 10,
'min' => 2,
'insertButton' => '.add-opcion',
'deleteButton' => '.remove-opcion',
'model' => $modelsOpc[0],
'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
'formFields' => [
    'titulo',
],
```

]); ?>

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="add-opcion btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="container-opciones">
<?php foreach ($modelsOpc as $indexOpc => $modelOpc): ?>
    <tr class="opcion-item">
        <td class="vcenter">
            <?php
                // necessary for update action.
                if (! $modelOpc->isNewRecord) {
                    echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelOpc, "[{$indexQuestion}][{$indexOpc}]id");
                }
            ?>
            <?= $form->field($modelOpc, "[{$indexQuestion}][{$indexOpc}]option")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Title option']) ?>
            <?= $form->field($modelOpc, "[{$indexQuestion}][{$indexOpc}]correct-option")->checkbox(array(
                'label'=>'',
                'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'padding:5px;'),
                //'disabled'=>true
                ))
             ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center vcenter" style="width: 90px;">
            <button type="button" class="remove-opcion btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Js

```
$script1 = <<< JS
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change","select",function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var optionsInput=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-justified';
        var index = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        var index_question = index.substring(0,1); 
        if ($(this).val()== 3) {
            $('#'+optionsInput).hide();
            $("label[for='" + optionsInput + "']").hide();
            $('#'+index_question).find('.opcion-item').not(':first').remove();
            $('#'+index_question).find('.opcion-item:first').hide(); 
        }else if ($(this).val()== 2){
            $('#'+optionsInput).show();
            $("label[for='" + optionsInput + "']").show();
            jQuery(".dynamicform_inner .add-opcion").each(function(indexQuestion) {
                $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).attr('type','radio').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $(".dynamicform_inner").on("afterInsert", function(e) {
                $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).attr('type','radio').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $(".dynamicform_inner").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
                $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).attr('type','radio').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $('#'+index_question).find('.opcion-item:first').show();
        }else if ($(this).val()== 1){
            $('#'+optionsInput).show();
            $("label[for='" + optionsInput + "']").show();
            jQuery(".dynamicform_inner .add-opcion").each(function(indexQuestion) {
                $( "input[type=radio]" ).attr('type','checkbox').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $(".dynamicform_inner").on("afterInsert", function(e) {
                $( "input[type=radio]" ).attr('type','checkbox').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $(".dynamicform_inner").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
                $( "input[type=radio]" ).attr('type','checkbox').prop("checked", false).show();
            });
            $('#'+index_question).find('.opcion-item:first').show();
        }else {
            $('#'+optionsInput).show().prop("checked", false);
            $("label[for='" + optionsInput + "']").show();
            $('#'+index_question).find('.opcion-item:first').show();
       }
});
```

JS;
$this->registerJs($script1);

Comment: if you are looking to select multiple options why not use checkbox instead of radio if i understand correctly

Comment: I try to use checkbox for multiple options and use radio for questions of a single correct option.

Comment: what I want is to keep an option selected from the "correct-option" of the radio buttons that are being added. @MuhammadOmerAslam